# Switching from formatted to unformatted input in C++

Tags: c++, istream

I have an input text file. The first line has two `int` numbers `a` and `b`, and the second line is a string. I want to use formatted input to do `file >> a >> b`, and then unformatted input to get the characters of the string one by one. In between the two steps, I need to skip over the `'\n'` character at the end of the first line. I used

```
  while(file.get()<=' ' && !file.eof());  // skip all unprintable chars
  if(!file.eof()) file.unget();           // keep the eof sign once triggered
```

to make the input format more flexible. The user can now separate the numbers `a` and `b` from the string using an arbitrary number of empty lines `'\n'`, tab keys `'\t'`, and/or space keys `' '` -- the same freedom he has to separate the numbers `a` and `b`. There's even no problem reading in Linux a text file copied from Windows when every end of line now becomes `"\r\n"`.

Is there an `ifstream` function that does the same thing (skip all chars `<=' '` until the next printable char or `EOF` is reached)? The `ignore` function does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) manipulator. It skips whitespace characters until a non-whitespace is found or end of stream is reached.. It is similar to use of whitespace character in `scanf` format string.

In fact, it is used by formatted input before actually starting to parse characters.

You can use it like that:

```
int x;
std::string str;
std::cin >> x >> std::ws;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
//...
//std::vector<int> vec;
for(auto& e: vec) {
    std::cin >> e;
}
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, str);
```

Comment: Whitespace is not defined as `<= ' '`, so this isn't the equivalent of the OP's solution. However, as described, it may satisfy the OP's actual requirement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it actually was VLA with user-provided size :P. But fixed.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Even though whitespace characters are only `' ','\n','\r','\t','\v','\f'`, for text files that's almost equivalent to `<= ' '`. Good solution!

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: C++ does not have VLAs